# JTCalendar delegate parameter type mismatch with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement in my application the amazing calendar view JTCalendarView.

I used cocoapod to configure the framework, then I'm following the guide provided by the author in the [github link](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar)

My problems come when I try to implement the delegates. For example in the page the author uses this method:

```
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
```

But when I try to implement the same method in my Swift project I have a different type for the variables. I have the following method:

```
func calendar(calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareDayView dayView: UIView!)
```

That, respect to the obj-c one doesn't have the type `JTCalendarDayView` for the dayView. Of course I can no more set the properties for this object.

By searching on the definition of the delegate protocol I saw that ALL the methods "lost" (has `UIVIew`) for the type of the last parameter.

Does anybody know where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Somewhat annoying.

```
if let myVeryOwnDayView = myDayView as? JTCalendarDayView {
  // from now on, work with myVeryOwnDayView
}
```